# Stats in v$sqlarea over time gets lower

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-tuning

I wrote an application that queries oracle v$sqlarea and dumps data to my own database for further analysis. I noticed something very strange - sometimes data in the v$sqlarea shows less executions than before. I'm pretty sure that the oracle cache was not cleaned (the first load time of query is still the same, and since I query oracle each minute I dont believe that in this one minute the query was executed 100k+ times).
Can anybody explain how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I asked this on Oracle forum as well, and I believe that the correct answer is this one
https://community.oracle.com/message/12980175#12980175